# Media query bracket condition

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to make a media query with a condition constructed this way:

```
((min-width: 300px), (min-height : 500px)) and (min-device-height: 1000px)
```

The problem is the condition inside brackets is either not being evaluated with priority or is treated as incorrect. My question is: can i nest the conditions like that, and if yes is that a correct synthax/what's the correct one? If not how can i achieve that with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`(min-width: 300px) and (min-height : 500px)) and (min-height: 1000px)`, try this. since "," does not seem to work for multiple media query screen conditions substitute "," by "and" wherever you require.